# Linkrot for arXiv trackbacks

Tags: support, trackbacks

When a question is deleted that contains an arXiv trackback, can we automatically delete the trackback on arXiv?

e.g. the second trackback at http://arxiv.org/tb/0903.1452 points to a deleted question.

Comment: Usually, fixing or removing a broken link is the responsibility of the maintainer(s) of the site containing the link, rather than the responsibility of the maintainer of the site the link refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Per Stefan's comment, someone will need to contact the arxiv administrators to remove a trackback.

I recall a while ago someone (the selectedpapers.net folks?) was trying to get hold of the complete list of trackbacks on the arxiv. Is this were available, it would be easy to filter out all the broken links.

We also have the list of all trackbacks we've sent to the arxiv, so one could check that list directly, also.

I recommend contacting the arxiv directly about this link, and if you think it is likely there are many more broken links (I doubt this), we can talk about detecting them.

Comment: There is data for all trackbacks https://arxiv.org/help/trackback/ I think there will not be that few broken links. For example,  http://arxiv.org/tb/1309.7675 likely soon will have not only one but two broken trackbacks. Surely an extreme case but still.(That question made my investigate this matter now, in case you should wonder why I came to this now.)